# How to pass a json object to node js server

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to create a hybrid mobile application where the backend is Node js that it will save data in mongodb my server works properly I prepared routes for handling users requests

I can get data from my server using GET method but my problem that I can't save data that is sended from ionic user interface using POST method. I tried to send   data using POSTMAN the data was saved succesfully in mongodb but the problem occur when I send data from mobile user interface

this is a picture to show the results in node js server of sending POST request using POSTMAN 
and sending POST request from mobile user interce

[image]

and this how data is saved in mongoDB

[image]

this is my routes file in node server

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/products')


    .get(function(req, res) {


      Product.find(function(err, products) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }

        res.json(products);
        });


    })

    .post(function(req, res) {


      console.log(req.body);

      var product = new Product(req.body);


      product.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }

        res.send({ message: 'product Added' });
      });
    });
```

this is the form

```
<label  class="item item-input">

            <input name="1" type="text" ng-model="product.nom" placeholder="nom du produit">
          </label>

          <label class="item item-input" >

            <input name="2" type="text" ng-model="product.unite" placeholder="unité de cette produit">
          </label>

          ...


          <div class="item button button-block button-positive" ng-click="createProduct(product)" >
          ajouter le produit
          </div>
```

and this is the controller of products :

```
app.controller('productController', function($http, $scope) {



    $scope.createProduct = function (new_prod){

    console.log(new_prod);

    var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },

                data: new_prod
            };  

    $http(req)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);


    }); 

    };
```

Comment: when you post from ionic, what says the response?

Comment: if its json, why are you posting with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? try `application/json` instead

Comment: @Gonzalo Pincheira Arancibia say the product is added but is saved in mongodb without any data

Comment: with the angular post you're getting JSON server-side, and with postman you're getting an object. clearly you sent it incorrectly with postman!

Comment: @Robbie because I do the same thing with postman post request with x-www-form-urlencoded and data is saved successfuly

Comment: You probably failed to include express middleware to handle json requests.

Comment: the problem that the json that is passed to node js server from mobile UI 
is not as I want to be . this is how it is passed
 { '{"nom":"rtd","unite":"dffd","img":"ds"}': '' }

Comment: Right, it's passed as json. `{foo:'bar'}` on the other hand IS NOT JSON.

Comment: But the JSON from POSTMAN is like this { nom: 'jus' }

Comment: **that isn't json!** that's what express is parsing the request data to, a javascript object.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try the idea of @ Robbie

Comment: thank you @Robbie for your reply the problem is solved !

Comment: i thought it might  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're posting JSON you shouldn't be using a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Use `application/json` instead.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627

application/x-www-form-urlencoded isn't for json, it's for data like you see in urls:

```
key=value&foo=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem it's related with CORS.

You need install https://github.com/expressjs/cors and use them like this in your express app:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());    

router.route('/products')


    .get(function(req, res) {


      Product.find(function(err, products) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }

        res.json(products);
        });


    })

    .post(function(req, res) {


      console.log(req.body);

      var product = new Product(req.body);


      product.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }

        res.send({ message: 'product Added' });
      });
    });
```

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: thank you @Gonzalo Pincheira Arancibia for your answer . the idea of Robbie solved my problem